# How can I use .Net system.drawing.drawstring to write right-to-left string (project is a dll)?

Tags: c#, gdi+, right-to-left

Hi
I need to create a bitmap file from an string, currently I'm using

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(106, 21);
Font f = new Font("Tahoma",5 );
StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();            
int faLCID = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR").LCID;
sf.SetDigitSubstitution(faLCID, StringDigitSubstitute.National);            
Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
Point pos = new Point(2, 2);
Graphics c = Graphics.FromImage(b);                        
c.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, m_width, m_length);
c.DrawString(stringText, f, brush, pos,sf);
```

it works but the problem is it is writing left to right. How can I make DrawString() to write right-to-left?
thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft`.

Comment: thanx slaks it is working. but now I should change the position where I started to write tex (2,2) -> (105,2)

Comment: @user: Draw in a `Rectangle` and set `StringFormat.Alignment`.